# Generic Implementation for Api call in c#

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, design-patterns

i have created one generic implementation for api call from all over my application.

```
 public class HttpClientService<TResult> : IDisposable where TResult : class
{
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public HttpClientService(string baseUrl)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
    }
    public TResult GetAPI(string url, Dictionary<string,string> urlParameters = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        string parameters = string.Empty;

        if (urlParameters != null)
        {
            parameters = BuildURLParametersString(urlParameters);
            url = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters) ? url : url + parameters;
        }

        if (headers != null)
        {
            AddHeaders(headers);
        }

        var response = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(url)).Result;
        var apiResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(apiResult);
        return result;
    }
    public TResult PostAPI(string url, Dictionary<string, string> formParameters = null, string jsonString = "", Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        HttpContent contentPost = null;
        if (headers != null)
        {
            AddHeaders(headers);
        }
        if (formParameters != null)
        {
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formParameters);
            contentPost = formContent;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        {
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            contentPost = content;
        }
        var response = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(url, contentPost)).Result;
        var apiResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(apiResult);
        return result;
    }
    private String BuildURLParametersString(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
        var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        foreach (var urlParameter in parameters)
        {
            query[urlParameter.Key] = urlParameter.Value;
        }
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        return uriBuilder.Query;
    }
    private void AddHeaders(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header.Value))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and from my application used like below

```
using (var clientService = new HttpClientService<GeoCodeResponse>("https://maps.googleapis.com"))
{
         var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         param.Add("latlng", $"{latitude},{longitude}");
         param.Add("result_type", "locality");
         param.Add("key", GoogleApiKey);

         var apiResult = clientService.GetAPI("maps/api/geocode/json", param);   
}
```

please suggest me what i am implemented is currect or any better improvement for code any changes.

Comment: I suggest using a single immutable `HttpClient` instance per API service. One potential problem with your approach: if you generate too many `HttpClientService<T>` in a set amount of time, you will run out of sockets, and thus encounter timeouts. Take a look at https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 3):

A few points that come to mind:

1. A lot of your code closely follows the underlying API of the HTTP client instance. It would be better to have a function that generates your client with its default settings (the ones you're setting in the constructor), then just use the appropriate methods on the `HttpClient`.
2. There arent many (any?) good use cases for calling `Result` on a task. You should make your method async and await the task instead.
3. Your use of `Task.Run` is redundant. You're wrapping one task inside another.
4. What happens if there is an error? Incorrect URI, no network etc...